# Calling AWS Sagemaker endpoint from Glue Job

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-glue, amazon-sagemaker

How to invoke AWS Sagemaker Endpoint from Glue Job ?

```
endpoint_name='I_created_EndPoint'
from sagemaker.predictor import csv_serializer, json_deserializer

predictor = sagemaker.predictor.RealTimePredictor(endpoint=endpoint_name)
```

However,  `import sagemaker` was giving error. Tried

```
import sys
import subprocess

# implement pip as a subprocess:
subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, '-m', 'pip', 'install',
'sagemaker'])
```

That too gave some error as

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/DataToMl", line 6, in <module>
    'sagemaker'])
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 363, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/usr/bin/python3', '-m', 'pip', 'install', 'sagemaker']' returned non-zero exit status 2
```

Comment: did you try boto3?  Please refer to the lambda section for python code snippet to call sagemaker using boto3, https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/call-an-amazon-sagemaker-model-endpoint-using-amazon-api-gateway-and-aws-lambda/

Comment: I am takling about GLUE,  not  Lambda.

Comment: are you using Glue python shell or Glue ETL job?

Comment: Im using Glue Job @Prabhakar Reddy

Comment: why do you want to use Glue ETL to just invoke an endpoint ? You can do it in multiple ways instead of using Glue ETL. Have you tried Glue python shell job?

Comment: See, what  I have is a Batch Processing need for a Big Data. Thats where I chose SparkGlue. 
My basic question is around Integrating The Amazon SageMaker Endpoints, into Batch ETL workflows on Glue or EMR.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63906124/integrating-the-amazon-sagemaker-endpoints-into-batch-etl-workflows-on-glue-or

Answer (score 2):

Glue jobs can include/install any Python Package by using the 'Security configuration, script libraries, and job parameters' section. We've done this for both sagemaker and awswrangler (both are super useful).

[image]

Under that section towards the bottom is a 'Job parameters' section.. add the following for the key  `--additional-python-modules` and `sagemaker` for the value (see image below)

[image]

NOTE: In addition to these steps you'll need to add a policy to your GlueJobExecution Role that allows `sagemaker:InvokeEndpoint`

Comment: After 2 years.. thanks anyways.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like the issue was installing sagemaker.

Were you able to `pip install` sagemaker directly from your environment? If not, what is the actual error? There might be some conflict dependencies.

Also, the sagemaker code you provided is sagemaker v1 (RealTimePredictor), you might want to change it to sagemaker v2 (Predictor) as `pip install sagemaker` will install sagemaker v2. For more information about sagemaker versions: https://pypi.org/project/sagemaker/#history