# Integrating The Amazon SageMaker Endpoints, into Batch ETL workflows on Glue or EMR

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-emr, aws-glue, amazon-sagemaker

How best can we have the said AWS Sagemaker ML model Endpoint configured via Glue, EMR based Spark Jobs ?

As we see in AWS Documentation ['here'](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/building-machine-learning-workflows-with-aws-data-exchange-and-amazon-sagemaker/) , An End point names as 'linear-learner-2019-11-04-01-57-20-572' is created.It can be invoked as

```
  response = client.invoke_endpoint(EndpointName='linear-learner-2019-11-04-01-57-20-572',
ContentType='text/csv',Body=values)
```

**However, assuming we have a batch job such that**

- scheduled batch job on a Big Data ,  Reads the data from a S3,  where
- it undergo a transformation of adding a new column as prediction
- result Output stored as S3.
- Could be triggered on Daily basis, or On Arrival of a new file in source folder

***How best can we have the said Endpoint configured via Glue, EMR based Spark Jobs ?***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

# Initialize Spark and Glue contexts
spark_context = SparkContext()
glue_context = GlueContext(spark_context)
spark = glue_context.spark_session

# Specify your SageMaker endpoint
endpoint_name = 'your-sagemaker-endpoint-name'

# Read data from S3 into a Spark DataFrame
s3_path = 's3://your-bucket/your-data-prefix/'
data_frame = spark.read.format('parquet').load(s3_path)

# Define a UDF  to invoke the SageMaker endpoint
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType

def invoke_sagemaker_udf(input_data):
    from sagemaker.predictor import Predictor
    predictor = Predictor(endpoint_name=endpoint_name, sagemaker_session=sagemaker_session)
    result = predictor.predict(input_data)
    return result

# Register the UDF
sagemaker_udf = udf(invoke_sagemaker_udf, StringType())

# Apply the UDF to the DataFrame
result_df = data_frame.withColumn("prediction", sagemaker_udf("input_data"))

# Perform any additional transformations if needed
# ...

# Write the result back to S3 or another destination
output_s3_path = 's3://your-bucket/your-output-prefix/'
result_df.write.format('parquet').mode('overwrite').save(output_s3_path)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Amazon Step Functions to create a workflow of actions and trigger each task one after the other (EMR, Glue, Athena, SageMaker, etc). Regarding batch tasks I recommend you consider launching a SageMaker Processing or SageMaker Batch Inference job

Comment: The Batch Inference is to induce transformation to the data and is not executed in a scalable manner. ( like Spark Job). Also in Batch Infrence the endpoint is innovoked as a RestApi.  That is taking the data over internet protocol to model.  Insead of bringing the model to the data.

Comment: if you don't like Batch Inference you can also use Spark in EMR or Glue or use the Processing Job :)

Comment: But how best to call the Model build in SageMaker from EMR ot GLUE ?